# Inline or not to inline in Haskell

Tags: haskell, inline, number-crunching

I have several number-crunching operations that account for a good portion of the CPU time. One example of such operations is this function:

```
import Data.Number.Erf
import Math.Gamma
import Math.GaussianQuadratureIntegration as GQI

-- Kummer's' "1F1" a.k.a M(a,b,z) Confluent Hypergeometric function
-- Approximation by the Gaussian Quadrature method from 128 up to 1024 points of resolution
kummer :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
kummer a b z err = gammaFactor * integralPart
    where
        gammaFactor       = (gamma b) / (gamma a * gamma (b-a))
        integralPart      = (integrator err) fun 0 1
        fun               = (\t -> (e ** (z * t)) * (1-t) ** (b-a-1) * t ** (a-1))
        e                 = exp 1
        integrator err
                | err > 0.1   =  GQI.nIntegrate128
                | err > 0.01  =  GQI.nIntegrate256
                | err > 0.001 =  GQI.nIntegrate512
                | otherwise   = GQI.nIntegrate1024
```

SO, I was wondering if there are some rules to follow about when a function should be INLINE to improve performance. REPA Authors suggest to:

> Add INLINE pragmas to all leaf-functions in your code, especially ones
>   that compute numeric results. Non-inlined lazy function calls can cost
>   upwards of 50 cycles each, while each numeric operator only costs one
>   (or less). Inlining leaf functions also ensures they are specialized
>   at the appropriate numeric types.

Are these indications also applicable to the rest of the numerical calculations or only to array computations? or is there a more general guide to decide when a function should be inline?

Notice that this post: [Is there any reason not to use the INLINABLE pragma for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709823/is-there-any-reason-not-to-use-the-inlinable-pragma-for-a-function) does not address directly the question about if the hints provided by the programmer truly help the compiler to optimize the code.

Comment: Style side-question: In the ``integralPart = `` line, would it not be more readable if he wrote ``(integrator err) fun 0 1``? (With brackets)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any reason not to use the INLINABLE pragma for a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709823/is-there-any-reason-not-to-use-the-inlinable-pragma-for-a-function)

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I'd follow this recipe. 1) Profile to be really sure this is a performance bottleneck. 2) Check GHC Core (-O2) to see if this is already inlined. 3) Experiment with inlining/LLVM/etc and see what happens (criterion might help here).

Comment: You might also want to experiment with [strictness bang patterns](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/strict.html)